# How can I cover text with input text?

Tags: html, css

I have a code that I'm trying to cover the text by images here is my code

```css
#example_form {
      display: flex !important;
    width: 100%;
}
#example input[type=text] {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu__list">
     <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" target="_self" href="#">Catalogue</a></li>
     <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" target="_self" href="#">Product Range</a></li>
     <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" target="_self" href="#s">News</a></li>
     <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" target="_self" href="#">Technology</a></li>
     <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" target="_self" href="#">Stockists</a></li>
     <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" target="_self" href="#">Videos</a></li>
     <li class="menu__item_search_button">
         <form id="example_form" action="/action_page.php">
               <input id="example" type="text" name="theTextInput" />
               <button type="submit" id="submit__search"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/24/000000/search.png"/></button>
                </form>
      </li>
</ul>
```

What I need is to cover the header links with text box, I already prepared JScript for `display:none` what I need is a code to cover the whole header like this one.

From this upon clicking 
[image]

will result to this
[image]

Comment: Please link the documentation you went through when researching how to achieve this. Also show us what you tried, linking the documentation saying what you tried should have worked.

Comment: Also create a [mcve]. What you posted doesn't have the CSS for the menu and menu items, and it's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an attempt, using vanilla JS and some CSS:

```js
document.querySelector('#example_form input').addEventListener('focus', toggleSearch);
document.querySelector('#example_form input').addEventListener('blur', toggleSearch);

function toggleSearch() {
  const form = document.querySelector('#example_form');
  const menu = document.querySelector('.menu__list');
  if (menu.classList.contains('expanded')) {
    menu.classList.remove('expanded');
    form.removeAttribute('style');
  } else {
    menu.classList.add('expanded');
    form.style.marginLeft = -(form.getBoundingClientRect().left - 8) + 'px';
    form.style.width = menu.offsetWidth + 'px';
  }
}
```

```css
.menu__list {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu__item {
  padding: 4px 8px;
  max-width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.menu__item_search_button {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#example_form input {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

#example_form {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  transition: all .35s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
}

#example input[type=text] {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu__list">
  <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" target="_self" href="#">Catalogue</a></li>
  <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" target="_self" href="#">Product Range</a></li>
  <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" target="_self" href="#s">News</a></li>
  <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" target="_self" href="#">Technology</a></li>
  <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" target="_self" href="#">Stockists</a></li>
  <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" target="_self" href="#">Videos</a></li>
  <li class="menu__item_search_button">
    <form id="example_form" action="/action_page.php">
      <input id="example" type="text" name="theTextInput" />
      <button type="submit" id="submit__search"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/24/000000/search.png"/></button>
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>
```